# How can i use Array.includes in typescript between different types

Tags: typescript

if Array.includes() result type is more tight type of input object type,
it makes error. how can i handle this?
this is the example of case.

index.d.ts

```
type OddNumberType = 1|3|5|7|9
type AllNumberType = OddNumberType|0|1|...|9
```

businessLogic.ts

```
let targetNumber:AllNumberType = parseInt(Math.random*10)
const oddArray:OddNumberType[] = [1,3,5,7,9]
let resultNumber:OddNumberType = 1;

if(oddArray.includes(targetNumber)){
 resultNumber = targetNumber
}
```

ts problem

```
Type 'AllNumberType' is not assignable to type 'OddNumberType'.
  Type 2 is not assignable to type 'OddNumberType'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you want to use `oddArray.includes` as if it is a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) which accepts an arbitrary number as its argument, and if it returns `true`, then Typescript should narrow the argument's type to be `OddNumberType`.

The `Array.includes` method is not declared as a type guard like this, and should not be: if a type guard returns `false` that should mean the argument is *not* of the type it guards, but generally if an array of some type `T[]` does not include an element, that does not mean the element is not of type `T`. There is something special about your array which makes its `includes` method a sensible type guard in this specific case - it is not just an array of `OddNumberType` values, it is an array of *every* `OddNumberType` value.

So, we can declare a type `ArrayOfEveryOddNumber` which is the same as `OddNumberType[]` but its `includes` method is a type guard:

```
type ArrayOfEveryOddNumber = OddNumberType[] & {
    includes(arg: AllNumberType): arg is OddNumberType
}
const oddArray = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9] as ArrayOfEveryOddNumber;
```

Note that a type assertion `as ArrayOfEveryOddNumber` is also needed.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBA8gEwQOQK4FsBGUBOAVSWAXhgEYAfAZnIFZyB2cgTlEJgEEAbTtLXA6DBIAGchQBMVcgBZa5AGwNyADmbBWg9jhwBDMHABmAUQBuufUl7YcQ+JYzWBUANoBdGADIYAb2Ax-MACWAHYAxpyoCFAAzgAUOjgA5gBcHNxW-IQAlKkJiUHRdigOmdDAAL7AoQD2wdEgMNVIWrpgts6kADQwlN003fTdTO46hS16hqbmiMV8OADc6gaoYSCBtTAgMSCxIHlQIBk4qVw8JfjZPn4BnAcwODGonIfnqTNHTrakiwFBBrFNBDjMAAOhC4UiMV2+xecyyWV8v1+D2iT1h1lseySByO138lUqQA)

Comment: This is beautiful. Just what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  for (const oddNum of oddArray) {
    if (oddNum === targetNumber) {
      resultNumber = oddNum;
      break;
    }
  }
```

for loop was answer.
array.find or array.includes can not use between different in&out type?

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix would be to add `as`:

```
const myArray: string[] = ["1", "2", "3"]
const value: number|string = ["1", 2, 3].random() 

myArray.includes(value as string)
```

It would be better if the param of `includes` accepts any type that includes the array's type.